# Smarty Compile path returns wrong result due to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in windows

Tags: php, windows, smarty

Hi I have moved my smarty project from my linux machine to windows machine , Now i am getting a wrong result for the compile path

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/smarty/templates_c\%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php
```

I checked it and found an issue in ths part

```
templates_c\%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php
```

the directy sperator is `\`so my path is failing .

I checked in this function in smarty

```
 function _get_auto_filename($auto_base, $auto_source = null, $auto_id = null)
    {
        $_compile_dir_sep =  $this->use_sub_dirs ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '^';
        $_return = $auto_base . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is returning `\` .

Is there any palce to change my `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` globally to `/` or is there any other solution for this . :)

Thank you in advance .

Comment: "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" being "\" is correct on windows though.

Comment: yes , but in other places in application  i have manually defined my paths using /  ,as an example C:/xampp/htdocs/smarty/templates_c is defined by me . in setup.php

Comment: You should also be using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` then if you need cross platform compatibility as it is a PHP predefined constant and not a smarty defined one.

Comment: @Scuzzy , ya that's the way it should be :) , thanks pal